# Remove data in Dictionary where the key is not present in a List

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ, is there a way to remove all items from a Dictionary, if the items keys are not present in a List?

Like an answer of this post, I do this like that:

```
var keys = dict.Where(kvp => !list.Contains(kvp.Key)).ToList();


foreach(va key in keys){dict.Remove(k);}
```

I'm just curious to find another way to do that...

Comment: Obviously, I have try with the classic way without LINQ...

Comment: @Maxime `I'm just curious to find another way to do that...` You have other answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is you can't loop over the dictionary; you have to get a list of keys first, otherwise the `foreach` loop will fail:

```
var kvps = dict.Where(kvp => !list.Contains(kvp.Key)).ToList();

foreach(var kvp in kvps)
{
    dict.Remove(kvp.Key);
}
```

or just

```
var keys = dict.Keys.Where(k => !list.Contains(k)).ToList();

foreach(var key in keys)
{
    dict.Remove(key);
}
```

Comment: Due to deferred execution, you're iterating the collection while you're mutating it, despite the fact that you're specifically warning about that possibility in your post.

Comment: @Servy: `ToList` immediately evaluates the query and creates a `List<>` from the results.  The `foreach` loop processes *that list*, not the query.  As such, D Stanley's solution will work fine.

Comment: @JonSenchyna He edited it 10 minutes after my comment.  Look at the revision history.

Comment: @Servy: My mistake.  I was just responding to a similar comment to the answer by QtX.  I checked the revision history on that one before I responded, but I forgot to in this case.

Comment: @JonSenchyna That comment was posted just 2 minutes after the original post.  Odds are it too was edit, but that post was fixed within the 5 minute grace period.

Comment: @Servy: It's possible, although I think my comment is useful in that case, since users reading the answer cannot tell that it was edited in response to the comment and may be mislead by it.  Either way, it's good practice for those answering a question to either leave a comment themselves, or a note in their answer, if they updated it in response to a comment.  That way they can prevent any confusion that may have been caused to other readers who simply see the answer and comments pointing out issues in it that no longer exist.

Comment: @Servy that's my fault - I did edit it in response to your comment and neglected to acknowledge it.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow Thanks, I was more illustrating that you can't remove the items, but have to get the key, and missed that distinction.

Comment: @DStanley replacing my prior comment with a correction. Your 2nd solution should be something like - `List<KeyValuePair<int, object>> toRemove = dict.Where(kvp => !list.Contains(kvp.Key)).ToList();` `foreach (KeyValuePair<int, object> kvp in toRemove) {list.TryRemove(kvp.Key, out object deletedItem);}`

Answer (score 8):

```
foreach(var key in  dict.Keys.Except(list).ToList())
{
    dict.Remove(key);
}
```

Comment: This would result in exception: `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

Comment: Or `myDictionary.Keys.Except(myList).ToList().ForEach(k => myDictionary.Remove(k))`

Comment: @Habib: The call to `ToList` at the end forces immediate evaluation of the linq query and puts the results into a new list.  Since QtX is enumerating that list, not `dict.Keys` itself, the `foreach` loop does not generate that exception.

Comment: @JonSenchyna I assume that the post was edited in response to Habib's comment.

Comment: @JonSenchyna, at the time of my comment there was not `ToList` in the answer. But it was added in the grace period